# Android Broadcast Not Received

Tags: android

I am testing BroadcastReceiver for my mini project. Code is bellow.

**1.Main.java**

```
package com.broadcast;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
    
        intent.setAction("com.example.TEST");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**2. MyReceiver.java**

```
package com.broadcast;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Broadcast Received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**3. AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
        <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.example.TEST"></action>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"></action>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
```

> Application runs fine But problem is that The Broadcast does not Received. And I could not identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registering and unregistering the `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically.

As per official document:

> If your app targets Android 8.0 or higher, you cannot use the manifest
> to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that
> don't target your app specifically).

Refer:
https://www.journaldev.com/10356/android-broadcastreceiver-example-tutorial